# Python 3 - Only numeric input

Tags: python, boolean, logic

I have trouble finishing a Python assignment. I'm using Python 3.0
So the program asks the user to input a set of 20 numbers, store them into a list, and perform calculation on it to output the largest number, the smallest, the sum, and the average.

Right now, everything is working, except one thing! In the event of a non numeric input from the user, I would like the program to ask for the input again.
I have trouble doing that, I thought of a Boolean variable, I'm not sure.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Here's my code :

```
import time

#Defining the main function
def main():
    numbers = get_values()
    get_analysis(numbers)

#Defining the function that will store the values    
def get_values():
    print('Welcome to the Number Analysis Program!')
    print('Please Enter A Series Of 20 Random Numbers')
    values =[]    
    for i in range(20):
        value =(int(input("Enter A Random Number " + str(i + 1) + ": ")))
        values.append(value)
        #Here we store the data into a list called "values"


    return values

#Defining the function which will output the numbers. 
def get_analysis (numbers):

    print(".................................")
    print("The Lowest Number Is:",  min(numbers))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("The Highest Number Is:", max(numbers))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("The Sum The Numbers Is:", sum(numbers))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("The Average The Numbers Is:", sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
    print(".................................")

main()
```

Vince

Answer (score 0):

I ran it on my Python 3 and got this

```
$ python3 so.py
Welcome to the Number Analysis Program!
Please Enter A Series Of 20 Random Numbers
Enter A Random Number 1: 3
Enter A Random Number 2: 4
Enter A Random Number 3: 2
Enter A Random Number 4: 6
Enter A Random Number 5: 4
Enter A Random Number 6: 3
Enter A Random Number 7: 5
Enter A Random Number 8: 6
Enter A Random Number 9: 8
Enter A Random Number 10: 9
Enter A Random Number 11: 7
Enter A Random Number 12: 6
Enter A Random Number 13: 5
Enter A Random Number 14: 4
Enter A Random Number 15: 3
Enter A Random Number 16: 2
Enter A Random Number 17: 4
Enter A Random Number 18: 6
Enter A Random Number 19: 7
Enter A Random Number 20: 1
.................................
The Lowest Number Is: 1
The Highest Number Is: 9
The Sum The Numbers Is: 95
The Average The Numbers Is: 4.75
.................................
```

This works fine. Now make a function like this one

```
import re
def isInteger(x):
    seeker = re.compile("-?[0-9]+")
    return bool(seeker.search(x))
```

You can use a loop with header

```
while not isInnteger(x):
    ##get number
```

to repeat until a number is actually entered.

Comment: Ok, thanks I think I got it. But am I supposed to code it this way?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes:

- added a `get_int()` function which prompts repeatedly until an integer is entered
- used this to simplify your `get_values()` function
- added a `how_many` parameter. Follows the "don't repeat yourself" principle - if you want to change the number of items, you can do it in one place
- moved the "welcome to the program" message out of `get_values` to `main` where it belongs
- Don't Capitalize Every Word Or Chuck Norris Will Get You
- I renamed `get_analysis()` to `show_analysis()` because it prints the result rather than returning it; accurate function names are important!
- I reduced the analysis to a data-driven loop; this is more a matter of taste than anything else, but I think it is cleaner and easier to understand, especially as the number of tests increases, and also contributes to Don't Repeat Yourself

and the final result:

```
import time

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            # couldn't parse as int
            pass

def get_values(how_many):
    return [get_int("Enter #{}: ".format(i)) for i in range(1, how_many+1)]

def average(lst):
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

def show_analysis(numbers):
    tests = [
        ("The lowest value is", min),
        ("The highest value is", max),
        ("The sum is", sum),
        ("The average is", average)
    ]
    print(".................................")
    for label,fn in tests:
        print("{} {}".format(label, fn(numbers)))
        time.sleep(.5)
    print(".................................")

def main():
    how_many = 20
    print("Welcome to the Number Analysis program!")
    print("Please enter {} integers".format(how_many))
    numbers = get_values(how_many)
    show_analysis(numbers)

main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I got it now!